# Python : Object is not avaialbe on different file

Tags: python, singleton

I have created a singlton Here is the class description.
allsms.py

```
from DB.models import ApiKey,ServiceProvider
from DB.messagenet import MessageNet


class SMSMgr( object ):
    _instance = None
    _allsp = []
    def __init__(self):
            pass
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance :
            cls._instance = super(SMSMgr, cls).__new__(
                                cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def loadsettings(self):
        get_all_sp = ServiceProvider.objects.filter(status = False)
        for obj in get_all_sp:
            cla = obj.class_Name
            a=globals()[str(obj.class_Name)](obj.userName,obj.password,obj.sendingurl)
            self._allsp.append(a)
            #print self._allsp
    def reload(self):
        self._allsp = []
        get_all_sp = ServiceProvider.objects.filter(status = False)
        for obj in get_all_sp:
            cla = obj.class_Name
            a=globals()[str(obj.class_Name)](obj.userName,obj.password,obj.sendingurl)
            self._allsp.append(a)


    def send(self):
        print "+++++++++++++++++++== Global send "

if __name__ == "__main__":

    b = SMSMgr()
    b.loadsettings()
```

Now in `test.py`  file of the same directory I am trying to use the singleton object which stored in the `_allsp`  variable like.

```
from SMShandler.allsms import SMSMgr

b = SMSMgr()
#b.loadsettings()

print b._allsp
```

This is printing empty list. But when I am doing like this:

```
b = SMSMgr()
b.loadsettings()
print b._allsp
```

it is printing the list of objects .

My question is, if the above design is singlton then why `print b._allsp` is printing empty list in `test.py`? I am already loading `loadsettings` in the `allsms.py` file .

Comment: Just a sidenote: I think it is a bit problematic to use this approach of creating a singleton. If one does not know the source code of the SMSMgr class he cannot anticipate the special behavior of the constructor. It is very confusing that two separate calls of SMSMgr() actually produce the same instance with the same attributes. From zen: 'Explicit is better than implicit.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `loadsettings()` in an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = SMSMgr()
    b.loadsettings()
```

The purpose of such a block is to happen only when the code is run directly (like `python allsms.py`). That means it won't happen when it is imported in the line:

```
from SMShandler.allsms import SMSMgr
```

If you put the line `b.loadsettings()` outside of the `if` block, you'll see that it will already be loaded.

Comment: Any way so that i can  call the loadsettings() at class instance made

Comment: See my edit. You could use put the line outside of the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.